# How to number multiple equations together with a right brace }

Tags: equations, align, numbering

How can one number a bunch of equations together with a right brace like shown below?

[image]

I work with the following document class:

```
\documentclass[pra,superscriptaddress, twocolumn,amsmath,amssymb]{revtex4}
```

and I tried the following but it doesn't work

```
    \begin{align}
           \left.
              \begin{split}
                    a &= b \\
                    c &= d \\
                    e &= f
             \end{split}
           \right\}
   \end{align}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Thanks, @Mensch. I hope my first question meets the quality requirements of this platform.

Answer (score 1):

Use `equation` instead of `align` for the outer and `aligned` instead of `split` for the inner environment.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \left.
  \begin{aligned}
    a &= b \\
    c &= d \\
    e &= f
  \end{aligned}
  \qquad
  \right\}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Have a look at section 3 of `amsldoc.pdf` (`texdoc amsmath`) for more details on the different math environments.